# Kotlin - IllegalArgumentException in overridden method

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalargumentexception

In Kotlin I'm overriding this two Google Sign-In functions:

```
override fun onConnectionFailed(result: ConnectionResult) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE)
            } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
            }

        } else {
            val gaa = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
            gaa.getErrorDialog(this, result.errorCode, 0)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        when (requestCode) {
            RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE -> if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient!!.connect()
            }
        }
    }
```

to check if the connection to google fails.

The problem is that sometimes, when I dismiss the dialog containing user accounts, which pop-up when the activity is launched

Like this one:

[image: dialog]

I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` with the following logcat

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.dancam.subscriptions, PID: 6346
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=6783, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.dancam.subscriptions/com.dancam.subscriptions.ActiveSubscriptions.Subscriptions_main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4126)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4169)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1552)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
>                         at com.dancam.subscriptions.ActiveSubscriptions.Subscriptions_main.onActivityResult(Subscriptions_main.kt:0)
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6937)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4122)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4169) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1552) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

that points to the `onActivityResult` function.

I tried changing

```
requestCode: Int
```

to

```
requestCode: Int?
```

But then I obviously get an error because the function is not the same as the one from it's superclass.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you need to mention `data` as `null` so do `data: Intent?` because `data` intent can be `null` when action is cancelled or no result was sent

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=6783, result=0,
>   `data=null`} to activity  Parameter specified as `non-null is null`:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
//                                                                           ^^
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, still gotta get my head around this non-null stuff in Kotlin :)

Comment: @Daniele i am glad that i could help and just keep on going, you'll get used to it very soon .

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue after closing Leaderboard window.

Comment: Thank you too !. This helped me to, not only sort the issue, but to understand the error